# error 500 in email forgot password magento

Tags: email, magento, hyperlink

my problem is the link in the email does not work when I click on it error 500 why ??

[this link i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRduM.png)

[forgotpasswordphtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzrIj.png)

[customerxml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLaHn.png)

Comment: Please give some more information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: what for information say to me i give you the informations

Comment: If I click forgot password on my page I have to specify my registration email. Then I do that  I get back to reset the email is inside that I have to use the link to reset my password but when I click on it then is coming error 500 page